# show plugin widget whenever I update my layer by adding a point

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, widget

I am developing a plugin that addresses the point layer, I want to add specific information to each point I add. For that, I need to write a script that make the Plugin widget pop out each time I add a new Point to my point layer inorder to be able to fill the attribute table through that widget. Any help?

Comment: The QGIS core functionality does not meet your requirments? Are you especially familiar with all functionality of attribute forms (drag/drop designer, ui-files, python fuctions on form load...)? Can you possibly describe your requirements to such "custom attribute form" in more detail?